# Como juntar vários Arrays?

Tags: javascript, array, typescript

Tenho um array que segue a seguinte estrutura:

```
[
  {
    title: "titulo 1",
    data: [{...}, {...}]
  },
  {
    title: "titulo 2",
    data: [{...}, {...}]
  },
  {
    title: "titulo 3",
    data: [{...}, {...}]
  },
]
```

E gostaria de percorrer esse array e juntar todos os array da chave `data` de cada objeto em unico array, como eu poderia fazer isso?

Comment: Isso: https://ideone.com/IEx9jg ?

Comment: @hkotsubo Segui esse trecho e consegui! Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Utilizando `reduce` podes obter um objeto com com todos os `data`. Não sei qual é o propósito mas precisares que iterar sobre ele, podes facilmente faze-lo utilizando `Object.keys`/`Object.values`.

```js
const initialData = [
  {
    title: "titulo 1",
    data: [{ a: 'a' }, { b: 'b' }],
  },
  {
    title: "titulo 2",
    data: [{ c: 'c' }, { d: 'd' }],
  },
  {
    title: "titulo 3",
    data: [{ e: 'e' }, { f: 'f' }],
  },
];

const finalData = initialData.reduce((acc, cur) => ({
  ...acc,
  ...cur.data.reduce((accInner, curInner) => ({
    ...accInner,
    ...curInner,
  }), {}),
}), {});

console.log(finalData);
```

Comment: Por algum motivo isso não funcionou, ele só me retornou um único objeto no final.